# I need to throw an user-defined error while there is no value for the entered key in the dict

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

The Exception is being created while there is no value for the key but `except` block is not invoked.

```
class NoElementError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        print("No element for this key")

data = { 1 : "vishnu" ,
         2 : "Murshid" ,
         3 : "vaseem" ,
         4 : "abdu" , 
         5 : "farooq" }

key = int(input("Enter key"))
try:
   data.get(key,NoElementError)
except NoElementError as e:
    print("Error",e)
```

The `except` block not called.

Comment: Returning the object `NoElementError` is a very different thing than actually `raise`ing it...

Comment: `dictionary.get(keyname, value)` where `value` is Optional. A value to return if the specified key does not exist. instead you can check `if data.get(key) is None: raise CustomUserException()`

Comment: `try: data[key] except KeyError as e: raise NoElementError from e`…?

Comment: @aleksandarbos That would also `raise` if the key exists, but its value is `None`, which is different from the key not existing.

Comment: Side question: why are you basically trying to implement `KeyError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this pattern more useful. In this example we try to access a hard-coded (missing) key

```
class NoElementException(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Missing key')

data = { 1 : "vishnu" ,
         2 : "Murshid" ,
         3 : "vaseem" ,
         4 : "abdu" , 
         5 : "farooq" }
try:
    try:
        print(data[99])
    except KeyError:
        raise NoElementException
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

**Output:**

```
Missing key
```

**Or:**

```
try:
    if 99 in data:
        print(data[99])
    else:
        raise NoElementException
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```